# Opening specific named csv-files and extract specific values into a matrix

Tags: matlab, date, csv

I am trying to open a csv file for each row of `yearticker` which is named according to the value of `yearticker`.

`yearticker = {'2013K';'2011WXK';'2013HDR'}`
`files: 2013K.csv, 2011WXK.csv, 2013HDR.csv`

But I dont want to open the whole file. I just want the return of the specific date from the `date` vector and 1 day before and 1 day after.

`date = [20030103;20110228;20130604]`

I would like to end up with a Matrix `M` like that with a column for each event of the date vector.

`M= [1 .057 .... ;0 .06;-1 .0633]`

It would be great if anyone could help me with this problem. Unfortunately my matlab skills are too low to get solutions for similiar problems to run for my problem.

`CSV file content: Days & Daily returns
Date, Return
20030101,.05
20030102,.057
20030103,.06
20030106,.06333`

Comment: See: [Import Text Data Files with Low-Level I/O](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html). As far as I'm aware, MATLAB does not have the ability to navigate to a specific line in a file. One option is to use [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to go line-by-line until you get to the line you want. Another option is to read in the entire file and search it after the fact.

Comment: Thank you. I am able to find a specific date manually with the reading data line-by-line example (litcount function) but I am not able to work with the resulat (`>> linebyline
1:20030103,.06 ans = 1`) and have no clue to how to run that for a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic working example using [MATLAB's low-level I/O](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/import-text-data-files-with-low-level-io.html):

```
date = '20030103';

nheaderlines = 1;

tdata_left = [];
tdata_center = [];
tdata_right = [];

ii = 1;
fID = fopen('test.csv', 'r');
while ~feof(fID) % Read in lines until we get to the end of the file
    tline = fgetl(fID); % Read in the next line of data
    if ii <= nheaderlines
        % Don't need to do anything until we get past the headers
        ii = ii + 1;
    else
        tdata_left = tdata_center; % Shift previous day's data left
        tdata_center = strsplit(tline, ','); % Split line at delimiter

        if strcmp(tdata_center{1}, date) == 1 % Compare the date to your query date
            % Matched, get one more line then stop reading from the file
            tline = fgetl(fID);
            tdata_right = strsplit(tline, ',');
            break
        else
            % No match, move on to the next line
            ii = ii + 1;
        end
    end
end

fclose(fID);

% Generate the final matrix
M = [ ...
     -1 str2double(tdata_left{2}); ...
      0 str2double(tdata_center{2}); ...
      1 str2double(tdata_right{2}) ...
     ];
```

Which returns:

```
M =

   -1.0000    0.0570
         0    0.0600
    1.0000    0.0633
```

In order to simplify my example I assumed that the date cannot be the first or last line in your data file. You will need to add a little bit of additional logic to handle this if it's a situation that can occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works. Two little questions: How can I deal with a file that doesnt exist if I run ur approach as a function ?  `inputvar = [cellstr(num2str(date(:))) yearticker];`
`for i = 1:311`
`inputvar2 = inputvar(i,:);`
`[M] = search(inputvar2{:});`
`V(:,i) = M(:,2);`
`end`

Comment: If [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) cannot open the file, it returns `-1`. You can use that with an `if` statement to decide whether or not to enter the `while` statement. You could also use [`exist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exist.html) in a similar manner.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Can you give me a final hint how I can solve my last little problem.  I get this Error message for a few files. I think it a appears at the empty or partly empty files. `Error in search (line 52) M = [ ...`
`Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.` Line 52 is that step where the loop tries to write the results to the Matrix M. I just want the loop to write 0 for the cases where he doesnt find data or uncomplete data in the file.

Comment: If you have a separate question related to your implementation of this answer it would be more beneficial to ask a new question rather than attempt to convey the information here in the comments.